# create multiple 2 d arrays of objects using javascript where object has same properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I create two 2-DArrays where each element of array is an object with properties . Both arrays are of different size and property of each cell is different.

```
var gridcell = [];
var regionalcell = [];
```

So far I have done this, It works but its not efficient i dont want to repeat the code. It would be great if you guys can help.

In both functions value of "w,h,r,c" is different.

```
function createCellArray(w, h,r,c) 
{
     for (j = 0; j < r; j++) 
     {
         gridcell[j] = [];
       for (i = 0; i < c; i++) 
       {
         gridcell[j][i] = 
            {
                 "x1": w * i,
                 "y1": h * j,
                 "x2": w * (i + 1),
                 "cell_color": null,
                 "y2": h * (j + 1),
                 "name": (i + 1 * (j * 10)) + 1
            }
        }
     }
}


function createRegionalCellArray(w, h, r, c) {
    for (j = 0; j < r; j++) {
        regional[j] = [];
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++) {
            regional[j][i] =
            {
                "x1": w * i,
                "y1": h * j,
                "x2": w * (i + 1),
                "cell_color": null,
                "y2": h * (j + 1),
                "name": (i + 1 * (j * 10)) + 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to really understand what is your issue... You want to factorize your code?

In this case, just make a function that return your common array:

```
function returnCellArray(w, h, r, c) 
{
     var cellArray = [];
     for (j = 0; j < r; j++) 
     {
       cellArray[j] = [];
       for (i = 0; i < c; i++) 
       {
         cellArray[j][i] = 
            {
                 "x1": w * i,
                 "y1": h * j,
                 "x2": w * (i + 1),
                 "cell_color": null,
                 "y2": h * (j + 1),
                 "name": (i + 1 * (j * 10)) + 1
            }
        }
     }

     return cellArray;
}

gridCell = returnCellArray(w1, h1, r1, c1);
regionalcell = returnCellArray(w2, h2, r2, c2);
```

Comment: Actually it seems to work, i think i was trying to use global array instead of local as you have used cellArray